# InfoPath 2010 Form ask for "Samart Card"

Tags: .net, sharepoint, certificate, infopath2010, custom-code

I am publishing an infopath 2010 form. This Form has Custom Code in VB.

I had to set the security level to "Full Trust" and then I needed to add a certificate:
[image]

Wictch I created with Digital Certificate for VBA Projects:

[image]

And all OK.. Until other users try to open the form and they are requeted to insert an SmartCard.....

[image]

Any Idea of What can I do to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te problem happens cause IP detects that the web services will acces resources in the computer... This is, my web service needs to create files in a server form Infopath Attachments base64 fields...

I "Solved" this problem implementig the WS directly in Infopath and not with custom code. In this case you don't need select "Full Trust" and in concecuense you don´t get that anoying request.

You can read more in this links:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa946782(v=office.14).aspx

https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Introduction-to-digital-signatures-d2f92222-abb1-486b-bc07-884ecac99c59

Now,  I chose Custom Code over infopath rules cuase the time out... and it happened. In contrast with Custom Code, with infopath rules and big files i get Time Out error.

So... Some one can help me with this point?